# How to create Calendar Overlay

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

How to create calendar overlay in SharePoint 2013 ?  please show me the direction that how i can do ? We have 7 department. Thanks

Comment: Go here: https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-calendar-overlay Explains it well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this Video please . It will help you

https://youtu.be/hdMwwSIEZE8

Answer (score 2):

1. From the home page of your SharePoint site, open a calendar you have created.
2. At the top of the page click Calendar to expand the ribbon.
3. In the Manage Views section click Calendars Overlay.
4. On the Calendar Overlay Settings page click New Calendar.
5. In the Name and Type section enter a name and select the type of calendar
6. In Calendar Overlay Settings enter the configuration
7. Review your settings and click OK.
8. You will now see your calendar listed under Additional Calendars, IT Calendar.

The step above taking from the following url:
https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-calendar-overlay

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links which can help you to create Calendar Overlay in SharePoint:

- [Overlay a SharePoint calendar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a)
- [How to Create a Calendar Overlay](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-calendar-overlay)
- [How to create a calendar overlay in SharePoint 2013 and 2010](http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2015/07/sharepoint-calendar-overlay-colors-how-to-create.html)
- [Video: SharePoint 2013: How to create a calendar overlay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfwc8wQOk-c)